# VPS with Ubuntu 18.04 NGINX Downloads PHP FILE

Tags: nginx, php, ubuntu-18.04

I have a VPS with:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Nginx
- Php7.2-fpm

The server runs Ruby on rails project as homeurl (example.com) and wordpress as directory (example.com/blog) .
First the VPS was configured with Apache2, made everything work fine, untill i had to integrate a live chat. Had to switch to Nginx for Action Cable.

Now, the chat app works fine, on RoR, but if i try to access the blog i get the index.php file to download, it does not execute.

Here is my nginx default conf:

```
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#

server { 

        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name localhost; 
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/asdfsf.net/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sdafasdf.net/privkey.pem;
        root /var/www/html/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_ruby /usr/local/bin/ruby;

location /var/www/html/public {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    

location ~ ^/blog(/.*|$) {

 root /var/www/html/public/blog;
        
         try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
        passenger_enabled off;       
        index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

        }

location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
   
        }


}
```

Spent 3 night on troubleshoting I cant get it right.
Any hint is very welcomed.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two regex matching locations and you don't have `fastcgi_pass` directive in the first one. Regex matching locations are checked from the first to the last one, so the second location (where you do have `fastcgi_pass` directive) will never be reached. That means any PHP file accessed with the `/blog/` URI prefix will be treated as a simple file and will not be passed to the PHP-FPM backend for execution. You can use two nested locations instead:

```
location ~ ^/blog(/.*|$) {
    passenger_enabled off;       
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

You don't need to define `root /var/www/html/public/blog;` for this location. You already have `root /var/www/html/public;` at the upper level, so nginx will search file `index.php` requested as `/blog/index.php` in the `/var/www/html/public/blog` directory (see the difference between [`root`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) and [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) nginx directives).

Comment: Now it is 404 Not Found.

Comment: If your `index.php` located in the `/var/www/html/public/blog` directory, remove `root` directive from this location.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind effort. I was at the end of my powers. Best regards !

Comment: Added some explanations. I also recommend you to read [this](https://serverfault.com/tour#:~:text=The%20person%20who%20asked%20can%20mark%20one%20answer%20as%20%22accepted%22.) :)